# The binary number is xor-or to get a negative number

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(
    `0000010100101000001111010011100` + ` ^` + `\n` +
    `1111111111111111111111111111111` + ` =` + `\n` +
    `${(0b0000010100101000001111010011100 ^ 0b1111111111111111111111111111111).toString(2)}`
);

console.log('\n' + '-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-' + '\n');

console.log(
    `00000010100101000001111010011100` + ` ^` + `\n` +
    `11111111111111111111111111111111` + ` =` + `\n` +
    `${(0b00000010100101000001111010011100 ^ 0b11111111111111111111111111111111).toString(2)}`
);
```

I'm doing an xor operation on two binary numbers.

This is normal when the number of bits is 31.

0000010100101000001111010011100 ^
1111111111111111111111111111111 =
1111101011010111110000101100011

However, the result become very strange when the number of bits is 32.

00000010100101000001111010011100 ^
11111111111111111111111111111111 =
-10100101000001111010011101

I want to know how to properly compute the xor operation of these two binary numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting **is** the correct XOR, it's just a display issue. All of the bitwise operations in JavaScript are defined as working on 32-bit integers (mostly signed ones, a couple of operations work on unsigned ones), so the `number` values (which are an IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point value) are converted to 32-bit ints, then the bitwise operation is done, and the result is converted back into a `number`. The signed ones are two's complement, so the most significant bit is a sign bit: 1 means the number is negative, 0 means it's positive. So the resulting `number` is negative when that bit is set. `toString` outputs the number in the number base you give, but as a signed value, so it starts with a `-` and doesn't output the sign bit.

You can get an unsigned version of it instead, for instance via a `Uint32Array`, and then output that:

```js
const a = 0b00000010100101000001111010011100;
const b = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;
const result = a ^ b;
console.log(unsignedBitString(a) + " ^");
console.log(unsignedBitString(b) + " = ");
console.log(unsignedBitString(result));

function unsignedBitString(n) {
    const uint = new Uint32Array(1);
    uint[0] = n;
    return uint[0].toString(2).padStart(32, "0");
}
```